Explicit expression on sheaf of graded algebras
Suppose $X$ is a quasi-projective variety over an algebraically closed field $k$. $Z$ a variety. Let $f: Z\rightarrow X$ be a projective morphism. And let $i: Z\rightarrow \mathbb P_X^n$ be the closed immersion associated to the projective morphism. Let $\mathcal{L} = i^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ and define the sheaf of graded $\mathcal O_X$ algebras as $\mathcal S = \mathcal O_X \oplus\bigoplus_{d\ge 1}f_*\mathcal L^d$.
Suppose $X =\text{Spec }A$ is affine, where $A$ is finitely generated as $k$ algebra. In this case $\mathcal O_X = A$. Could someone explain why $\mathcal f_*\mathcal L = \Gamma(Z, \mathcal O_Z(1))$ in this case? Basically I want to show  $\mathcal S$ correspond to $S = A \oplus\bigoplus_{d\ge 1}\Gamma(Z, \mathcal O_Z(d))$.
Edit: $k$ is assumed to be algebraically closed--otherwise I don't think this would be true(?)

Ok I will make an attmpt to answer, but please let me know if this is correct:
Since $\mathcal L$ is an invertible sheaf, which by definition would be coherent, so that we have the identity
$$
\Gamma(X,f_*\mathcal{O}_Z(1))=(f_*\mathcal{O}_Z(1))(X)=\mathcal{O}_Z(1)(f^{-1}(X))=\mathcal{O}_Z(1)(Z)=\Gamma(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z(1)).
$$
So suffice to show $\mathcal{O}_Z(1)\cong i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^n_A}(1)$, but $i: Z\hookrightarrow \mathbb P^n_A$ is a closed immersion.
Now both $Z$ and $X$ are assumed to be varieties over algebraically closed field $k$, then we see that it induces a surjective map $\mathcal O_Z(1)\rightarrow i^*\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^n_A}(1)$ on invertible sheaves, so that this is an isomorphism by Hartshorne Ex. 7.1.
And indeed the $d$-twisting case follows similarly.
